# Twitter Share button title issue

Tags: html, api, twitter, facebook-opengraph, title

I am using a twitter share button and I noticed that the title inside the twitter share is from my HTML title `<title>My Page</title>` is it possible to change the twitter title to my meta og:title instead?

For some reason I thought the Twitter share uses whats in the meta og:title.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add:

```
data-text="Your title here"
```

To the button markup itself as per [this documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) - <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> "`data-text`"

Not as clean as using the same Graph API tag but it should do the trick!